# Different Levels of Approval using Power Automate (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

I am currently developing a power automate flow for my company where we need a document stored in a SharePoint list to be approved at different levels of management.

Is it possible to write a flow where if the first approver approves the document it moves to the next approver and if they reject it then it doesn't move forward to the next approver and the person submitting the document is notified. The document is supposed to move through at least 3 or 4 different levels of approvers.

I am not quite sure on how the structure of flow should be. Is there a particular way I should go about this and are there any resources that I can refer too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple levels of approval using Power Automate.

For your requirements you can create sequential approvals. Check below references for detailed information:

**Microsoft documentation**: [Manage sequential approvals with Power Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/sequential-modern-approvals)

**Other Reference**: [MS FLOW APPROVAL FOR MORE THAN 5 APPROVERS IN SHAREPOINT](https://www.theblueflamelabs.com/approval-ms-flow-for-more-than-5-approvers-in-sharepoint/)

**Note**: Flow definition limits are changed. You can check updated limits in below reference link. Currently, Allowed nesting depth for actions is 8. If you requires more nesting depth in your flow then you should consider adding child flows for your requirements.

[Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#flow-definition-limits)

**Additional Reference**: [Create child flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)